# Operations on file | get and put pointer

Tags: c++, database, file

I have some questions on manipulating on a file ;

a.) I am a bit confused about get and put pointer in c++. Do I show correct position of get pointer and put pointer.

```
MyFile . seekg ( 0 , ios :: beg ) ;
MyFile . seekp ( -10 , ios :: end ) ; 

index :0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10  ...          -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0  
        __________________________________________________________________
       ^                                      ^               
       ^                                      ^                                  
       ^                                      ^
   get Pointer                               put pointer

Myfile . get ( character ) ;          
MyFile . write ( SomeString, 4 ) ;
MyFile . flush ( ) ;

index :0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10  ...          -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0  
        __________________________________________________________________
         ^                                             ^               
         ^                                             ^                         
         ^                                             ^
      get Pointer                                  put pointer
```

i.) Are Seekg and seekp always guarentee that get an put pointer always shows correct position ?
  ii.) If you know more about this topic, can you show/give me some point(s) I should be careful when I use them, ( if there is )

b.)   Is

```
   FileIN . seekg ( 1, ifstream :: cur ) ;
```

equal to

```
   FileIN . seekg ( 1, ios :: cur ) ;
```

Platform : linux 
File format : binary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a) It's wrong. File streams maintain *one* file pointer, for both input and output. Both `seekg` and `seekp` do the same thing. The reason there are two different functions is that the interface of iostreams is generic, it can be used for devices which do have separate put and get pointers.

Quote from the standard [filebuf]:

> In particular:
>
> — If the file is not open for reading the input sequence cannot be read.
>
> — If the file is not open for writing the output sequence cannot be written.
>
> — **A joint file position is maintained for both the input sequence and the output sequence.**

b) Yes, they are the same.

**EDIT:**

```
index :0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10  ...          -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0  
       _____________________________________________________________________
       ^ file-pointer

MyFile . seekg ( 0 , ios :: beg ) ;

index :0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10  ...          -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0  
       _____________________________________________________________________
       ^ file-pointer

MyFile . seekp ( -10 , ios :: end ) ; 

index :0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10  ...          -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0  
       _____________________________________________________________________
                                             ^ file-pointer

Myfile . get ( character ) ;
// you must sync/flush if your last operation was input and you switch to output,
// or your last operation was output and you switch to input.
MyFile . sync ( ) ;

index :0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10  ...          -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0  
       _____________________________________________________________________
                                                 ^ file-pointer

MyFile . write ( SomeString, 4 ) ;
MyFile . flush ( ) ;
index :0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10  ...          -10 -9 -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0  
       _____________________________________________________________________
                                                             ^ file-pointer
```

Comment: "File streams maintain one file pointer, for both input and output" Can you give me more explanation   ?

Comment: @fatai: You'll have to explain first what you don't understand.

Comment: If you have time , can you show me by sketching,like I did,  what you try to tell me.

Comment: My last question, Do  file pointer point to already read/written byte ? Ex: For last case, file-pointer points to "index -5", have byte on "index -5" alrady be  written ?

Comment: @ybungalobill, While I have been examining your answer, one question came my mind. I have googling it but I can't find any reliable information. So, I have decided to ask you, Do sync and flush equal to each other ? Moreover, Can sync be use with fstream ?

Comment: @gcc: good question. Both call `rdbuf()->sync()`, but before that they construct a sentry object which is different for `ostream` and `istream`. The only relevant difference I can find is that the destructor of `ostream::sentry` is required to call `rdbuf()->sync()` *again* if `flags() & ios_base::unitbuf` is set...

Comment: @ybungalobill, Can you add this comment to your answer? And Can you specify which one more appropriate to this case, which fatai gives some code ?

Comment: @ybungalobill, Now I am a bit confused like fatai :). Do index on a file start with 0 ? In other words, Do 0 index at end be an index of  eof ? If yes, why is it not shown as it should be?

Comment: @gcc: the more appropriate in this case is probably `f.seekp(f.tellg());`. Yes, `f.seekp(0, ios::end)` seeks to the one-past-the-end, that is to the end of the file. Where it's not shown?